# QObject objectName not showing in autocomplete

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator

Im working on a program using QtCreator 2.4.1. The problem is that when I add a widget in QtDesigner with name Widget1 for example and then try to call the widget using ui::Widget1 autocomplete does not seem to work.

It shows all the blue colored options like aboutAction, aboutMenu, cameraResolutionLabel but does not show the name of the widget, which is really annoying because if I forget the name of the widget I have to go back to QtDesigner interface to check it out.

To ilustrate:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui-> "HERE IS WHERE THE NAMES DONT SHOW UP"
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you have to re-run qmake and rebuild your project for new widgets to show up in autocomplete. This usually forces Qt Creator's intellisense-equivalent to re-parse all of the files.

Another possibility is that a bug somewhere else in the code is causing the compiler to not recognize your new class as a class. Make sure you've `include`d everything that you need to.

Comment: Thanks, it was a weird bug, I had this project opened [OpenCV Multithreaded](https://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/) as I've been working with it, and when I checked the include it turns out my project was including the "ui_mainwindow" file from the other project, the moment I closed it and recompiled the problem was solved.

Comment: Yeah, I've had that happen a few times, too. Unfortunately I haven't noticed that it consistently enough to report as a bug yet.